# Trouble with encapsulating "recursive types" in Scala

Tags: scala, type-safety, parameterized-class

Sorry, I have hard times figuring out a relevant title for my problem.

I want to model the following behavior: I designed a "language" with expressions that encapsulate standard Scala types. Expressions can be either variables or sequences of expressions. In the following, A can be a standard Scala type (namely Boolean, Int, Double). I also want to implement a method to replace expressions by other in expressions (particularly in sequences). I tried some code which I cannot manage to compile. I placed quotation marks when I do not really know what type to put but all the this is probably messy. I have special trouble with the Sequence thing, due to its recursive nature.

```
sealed trait Expression[A] {
  def replace[B](a: Expression[B], b: Expression[B]): Expression[?]
}

trait Variable[A] extends Expression[A] {
  def replace[B](a: Expression[B], b: Expression[B]) = 
    if (a == this) b else this
}

case class Sequence[A <: Expression[B]](values: Seq[A]) extends Expression[A] {
   def replace[B](a: Expression[B], b: Expression[B]) = 
     if (a == this) b
     else Sequence(values.map(_.replace(a, b)))
}
```

I assume of course that sequences are acyclic (a sequence cannot contain itself) as it would trigger an infinite recursion. These are used to implement n-ary matrices.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI, good design is about separation of concerns. You should consider separating the data model and behaviour. I.e., neither `Expression` or `Sequence` should have any methods and the `replace` function should be implemented externally.

Comment: BTW, do you have an understanding of what you need the type parameters for? Because unless you plan to do type-level programming there is no point in having them.

Comment: Well, yes I have the use for additional type checking for my DSL. However, I have the alternative to code different traits (which was I was doing before): IntExpression, DoubleExpression, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you ran into one of those corner cases where Scala does not have an elegant solution.

What you need in the place of `Expression[?]` as the return type is actually a type that represents "this type", being the type that the trait is actually mixed into. There is no shorthand in Scala that lets you express this in a simple way, and you cannot use `this.type` either, as that is too specific and can only be used when you really always return `this`.

The solution usually quickly introduces mind-bending boilerplate. The Scala collections for example suffer from the same issue, traits like `MapLike` need to encode similar things.

I tried to quickly modify your sample to encode such a type. I made sure it compiles, but I did not run it:

```
sealed trait Expression[A, ThisType <: Expression[A, ThisType]] {
  def replace[B,C <: Expression[B,C]](a: Expression[B,C], b: Expression[B,C]): ThisType
}

trait Variable[A] extends Expression[A, Variable[A]] {
  def replace[B,C <: Expression[B,C]](a: Expression[B,C], b: Expression[B,C]) = 
    if (a == this) b.asInstanceOf[Variable[A]] else this
}

case class Sequence[A <: Expression[_,A]](values: Seq[A]) extends Expression[A, Sequence[A]] {
   def replace[B,C <: Expression[B,C]](a: Expression[B,C], b: Expression[B,C]) = 
     if (a == this) b.asInstanceOf[Sequence[A]]
     else Sequence(values.map(_.replace(a, b)))
}
```

It even has to use a cast, which usually is a smell on its own, but I'm not sure there is a way to avoid it in this case. At least it is safe, we know it has to have the right type, just the compiler does not know it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Usually in situations like this there is a required relationship between `A` and `B`. E.g., consider what happens when you add an element to a (hypothetical and highly simplified) sequence type:

```
class Sequence[+A] {
  def +: [B >: A](b: B): Sequence[B] = {
    /* Build the new sequence with b at the beginning and this sequence's elments after */
  }
}
```

So in your case (if this pattern applies for you), signature in `Expression[A]` would be:

```
def replace[B >: A](a: Expression[B], b: Expression[B]): Expression[B]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. I ended simplifying up my problem to obtain a simpler solution. I simply "flattened" the type parameter of sequences:

```
case class Sequence[A] (values: Seq[Expression[A]]) extends Expression[A] {
  def replace[B <: A](a: Expression[A], b: Expression[B]) {
    // (Code in initial question)
  }
}
```

`A` in `Expression` now means that `Expression` is either a variable of type `A`, a sequence of variables of type `A`, a sequence of sequence of variables of type `A`…

I lose expressiveness here, but gain in usability. Having two parameters for Expression was getting too complicated, and broke Java interoperability. Maybe I will try to improve this on later.